# Is there a way to get the real address of bit.ly?

Tags: url-shortener, bit.ly

I'm working on understanding the original web page of `bit.ly` `hrefs`, and I would like to know if there is a way to get at the real address of the bit.ly using python. Any advice/directions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the bitly shortened url is yours you can use api to get all info for that shortened link including original link. If the link is not yours, not possible to know the original link unless you click it.